# why here document make cat blocked

Tags: bash, heredoc

I have a program like this:

```
cat | cat << EOF
some content
EOF
```

After I press "EOF" and enter, the second cat displays `"some content\n"` on my terminal, I ps aux and found the second cat has exited.  But the first cat is blocked and is not exiting.

Strace shows that the first cat is blocked by `read(0,`, if I press another enter (second enter) the first cat's `read` returns(got an "\n") and try to print the "\n" to pipeline, and encounter a sigpipe.

My problem is, why the first cat is blocked?  Or why the content...EOF does not give the first cat a end of file?

Another problem is, since the first cat has not close its fd/1(stdout), why the second cat exit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your here document is redirected to the standard input of the *second* cat, which explains all of your observations.  What you meant seems to be

```
(cat | cat) <<EOF
some content
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you!  Or this way also works: `cat << EOF | cat \nsome content\nEOF`